# Ng-Animate doesn't work with Chrome

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate, animate.css

I have some compatibility problems between Chrome and Firefox. I use ng-view to create an animation (with ng-ng-enter and leave). Here is an example with a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Vo2cJ72DO0a5aSCipkvg?p=preview

**style.css**

```
    .view.ng-leave, .view.ng-enter{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.view.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeOut;
    -ms-animation-name: fadeOut;
    -o-animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-name: fadeOut;
}
.view.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -ms-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -o-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
 }
```

When I execute the plunker Firefox, no problems, I have an animation.
But when I execute in Chrome, I did not work, but I'm prefix -webkit-

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ng-view>` is a `HTMLUnknownElement`.

Seems like animations doesn't work with HTMLUnknownElements in chrome.

Changing `<ng-view>` to `<div ng-view>` worked for me.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/DT5xcxgficbdu8CaFTlT?p=preview

Comment: It also doesn't work even if you register the element name ^^ Some chrome bug.